# How could I Nest a SELECT query and check it against a top level SELECT value?

Tags: sql

I am recently learning SQL and am working with an existing database that I am not able to alter.

We have a table with a list of every ones accounts. Top level accounts have the option of having a "sub account". What I want to do is make a report of all of the sub accounts with a column for their "Top Level Account Owners".

Here is a sample table.

```
LName AccountType   AccountID OwnerID
Amber SubAccount    A1        A3
Bob   SubAccount    A2        A3
Ken   MasterAccount A3        A3
Jim   SubAccount    B1        B3
Sam   SubAccount    B2        B3
Fred  MasterAccount B3        B3
```

With this I want to make a report of all of the sub accounts with the master account holders name . Something like this

```
SubAccountHolder MasterAccountHolder
Amber            Ken
Bob              Ken
Jim              Fred
Sam              Fred
```

Basically combining 2 records into 1 from the same table when record 1's ID matched another records OwnerID. If a persons ID and Owner ID match then they are the master account for those sub accounts. I use this to find all of the master accounts. Then I want to filter that to show only the one master account per record and add it to the sub accounts record in a report.

Here is the actual code I am working with so far

```
SELECT Users.FirstName, 
    Users.LastName, 
    Users.Phone, 
    Users.Email, 
    Accounts.SetupDate, 
    AccountStatus.Name AS AccountStatus, 
    Accounts.WLCOwnerID,
    WLCOwner = STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + Users.Email
        FROM Accounts 
            INNER JOIN UserAccounts ON Accounts.WLCOwnerID = UserAccounts.UserID
            INNER JOIN Users ON UserAccounts.UserID = Users.ID
        WHERE Accounts.WLCOwnerID = UserAccounts.UserID
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 1, 1, '')

FROM AccountStatus INNER JOIN (
        (
            (AccountTypes INNER JOIN Accounts ON AccountTypes.ID = Accounts.AccountTypeID) 
            INNER JOIN UserAccounts ON Accounts.ID = UserAccounts.AccountID
        ) 
        INNER JOIN Users ON UserAccounts.UserID = Users.ID
    ) ON AccountStatus.ID = Accounts.StatusID

WHERE Accounts.AccountTypeID=6 AccountStatus.Name='SubAccount'

ORDER BY Accounts.SetupDate DESC;
```

So my top level SELECT is a query to get all of the account holders information  Then my nested SELECT is a list of all of the master account holders Email Addresses. I want to make a report of all of the sub account clients attached with their master account holders email address.

The issue I am having is while in the nested SELECT I want to match the master accounts IDs to the top level sub accounts IDs of their master account holder. And sadly both types of accounts are in the same table and I don't have an option at this point to "fix" the tables to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.lname SubAccountHolder,
       b.lname MasterAccountHolder
  FROM accounts a
  JOIN accounts b
    ON a.ownerid = b.accountid
 WHERE a.accounttype = 'SubAccount'
   AND b.accounttype = 'MasterAccount';

+------------------+---------------------+
| SubAccountHolder | MasterAccountHolder |
+------------------+---------------------+
| Amber            | Ken                 |
| Bob              | Ken                 |
| Jim              | Fred                |
| Sam              | Fred                |
+------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: In this example what does "a" and "b" represent? Is it a way to name a table so that you can join 2 of the same tables?

Comment: a and b is just an alias so the database engine does now from which base table the column "lname" has to be taken - this is important if you join tables and working on columns which exist in both tables. the RDBMS would not know which table you mean so you have to specify that by an alias or the full table name in front of the column (depends on the RDBMS which option you may or must choose)